# Changing admin route from 'admin/' to 'customadmin/'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nginx, spree

All.  I've googled this quite a bit and I haven't found anything that'll work.

I want to change the admin route to something other than "admin".  In this case, we'll just use "customadmin" as the desired name.

I've been toying with two solutions.  One uses rewrites with Nginx, the other uses the routes in the spree application. Maybe, I should use both.

I'm doing this for the SSL layer, so in my 443 server section, (for the Nginx Solution) I tried the following:

```
locaton /customadmin/
{
    rewrite ^/customadmin/(.*)$ /admin/$1 permanent;
}
```

Cool.  That maps customadmin to all the admin routes.  But What I don't want is for any random user to even get to the /admin section.  Also, If I'm mapping 'customadmin' to 'admin' it'll probably create some sort of error.

Ideas:
*Should I use the 'internal' property?  That is, in the admin  location block, only go somewhere if the request is internal (or from a rewrite)

*Is there a way to namespace /admin in my spree application so that it uses 'customadmin' instead?  I know it can be done (somewhat) by doing the following:

```
Spree::Core::Engine.routes.append do
    scope :customadmin do
        namespace :admin do
            resources :my_model
            resources :my_other_model
        end
    end
end
```

Environment Specs:

Spree: 2.1.2

Ruby: ruby-2.0.0-p353

rails: 4